# How can I display time like 30 seconds ago or 2 hour ago and update up to days in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Hi there I am developing a social application I want to display passed time i.e when the post was created like Facebook for examples created 30 seconds ago or created 2 hour ago and up to days in react-native

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) for the same

Example can be :

```
moment([2022, 05, 22]).fromNow(); // 2 days ago
```

Or you can pass any date object and use `fromNow()`

You can get following output based on criteria

[image]

Comment: Do I need to use date picker element also?

Comment: No, you just need to pass date object or create a moment object

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion better library for updating date is `dayjs` or `date-fns`. Both libraries are light weight. Specially if you are creating social app where I assume you would like to render a lot of dates.

https://date-fns.org/

https://day.js.org/
In `dayjs` what are you looking for is: `dayjs(someDate).fromNow()` from is output like this: `3 minutes ago`

Comment: Wittbrodt Do I need to use date picker element also?

Comment: Hmm I don't understand why you would need to use date picker element. Answer for your question is only what I suggested in my answer.
There is extended code what I mean https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/from-now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help friends  I have found my answer. It was a single line and easy using 'moment' library here is how I got it:

```
 let createdAt = moment(moment.now()).fromNow();
```

for display

`<Text> Createdat: {createdAt} </Text>`